# Is the creature in "The Thing" a single creature?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-thing

I have just finished the 1982 film "The Thing" and it left me feeling very confused.

How many "Things" were there in the film? As far as I understand it the filmmakers tried to explain it as a virus that spreads but that doesn't make sense as it also seems to be a living organism. In that case does that mean every person imitated by the thing was a self-reproduced creature of the same species.

Or was it the same creature throughout the film? I don't understand this either as it is killed multiple times.

Comment: Required reading: _[The Things](http://clarkesworldmagazine.com/watts_01_10/)_ by Peter Watts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> In that case does that mean every person imitated by the thing was a self-reproduced creature of the same species.

### Yes...this precisely.

As you state, there are multiple instances of a creature being destroyed.

Each instance of the "Thing" is independent of the others but that's not to say they don't function together or in concert to achieve their goal.

From the script

> ```
>                                 MACREADY
>                      Watching Norris in there... gave me 
>                      the idea that maybe every part of 
>                      you bastards is a whole. Every piece 
>                      of you is self-sufficient, an animal 
>                      unto itself. When a man bleeds it's 
>                      just tissue. But blood from one of 
>                      you Things won't obey. It's a newly 
>                      formed individual with a built-in 
>                      desire to protect its own life. When 
>                      attacked, your blood will try and 
>                      survive -- and crawl away from a hot 
>                      needle say.
> ```

Comment: To get slightly *more* precise...each individual cell is it's own creature that can work in cohort with other cells as a single or multicelled individual. This is one of the reasons why the creature has such unfathomable control of it's self and replicating abilities.

Comment: Does that mean disparate bits of Thing could re-merge into a single creature?

Comment: @StephenR that is not explored in the movie, so we don't have a way to know. But if it _reproduces_ when a bit separates then it's an offspring, and offsprings usually don't merge back with the mother (in nature at least) - I might be wrong.

Comment: @Luciano True. I was thinking it might work as a sort of “hive” creature, like the Borg. Each cell is a distinct entity, but they all collectively constitute a single entity with multiple bodies. Depends on how you define “entity”, but we’re talking an alien here.  Not contradicting the answer above, just expanding and theorizing

Comment: It seems it might be a hive mind. Millions of cellular creatures working as a whole